# Why isn't this configuration saving?

Tags: configuration

How do I do change configuration when there is a dash in the yml file?

The configuration is the following one.

```yaml
source:
  plugin: url
  data_fetcher_plugin: http
  data_parser_plugin: xml
  urls:
    - 'private://migrations/migration.xml'
```

I need to change it to the following.

```yaml
source:
  plugin: url
  data_fetcher_plugin: http
  data_parser_plugin: xml
  urls:
    - 'private://migrations/2023-05-01/migration.xml'
```

I tried the following code, but it does not work.

```php
$this->configFactory()
  ->getEditable('migrate_plus.migration.my_migration')
  ->set('source.urls', $file_values->uri);
```

```php
$this->configFactory()
  ->getEditable('migrate_plus.migration.my_migration')
  ->set('source.urls', [$file_values->uri]);
```

Comment: What is the outcome of the things you tried? You haven't mentioned what isn't working here.

Comment: Did you call `save` after `set`?

Comment: Of course `->save();`. Smh. Thank you.